# Why is this question not in the list of unanswered questions?

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

[This question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9407/2469) has 12 upvotes, and currently no answers with positive scores. Why does it not appear in the [list of unanswered questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/unanswered)?

This seems to be a bug, so I am tagging it as such, but please change the tag if I am understanding something incorrectly?

**Update:**

It has now been a month since this occurred and the question is still not on the unanswered list. Community user bumped it again today, so I guess the algorithm that runs for that is different from the one that puts a question on the unanswered list? Are the prerequisites for those two things different?

Comment: I wonder if it might be related to this: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/1459/22.  A lot of votes were recently invalidated across the network, so it's possible that the answers *were* upvoted and just aren't anymore.  Maybe a caching problem?

Comment: @goldPseudo: I believe that is correct. Until yesterday, one of the answers _was_ positively scored.

Comment: @JonEricson Thanks for following up. The only reason the issue even occurred to me was because Mr. Community bumped the question today, and I think the requirements for that are the same as the requirements for being listed in the Unanswered Questions tab. So, eventually it will be listed as an unanswered question, right?

Comment: @JonEricson ping. 2 weeks later and the question is still not on the unanswered list.

Comment: @Daniel: I've removed the by-design status. Clearly something is out of whack here.

Comment: @JonEricson Do you know who I could ping to investigate this?